# Do you know how to read Protractor errors?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, automated-tests, protractor

Can you teach me how to find the unexpected colon that Protractor is telling me about? There's a lot of what looks like diagnostic information there but I have no idea how to interpret it.

Every time I run a Protractor test it gives an error about one thing or another, so it may be useful if there's a way to locate it quickly.

```
[firefox #1] 1) Protractor Test encountered a declaration exception
[firefox #1]   Message:
[firefox #1]     SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
[firefox #1]   Stack:
[firefox #1]     SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
[firefox #1]         at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
[firefox #1]         at require (module.js:384:17)
[firefox #1]         at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\Users\travi\Documents\protractor\Experiments\20151030\tests\OnlineDonation-Match-NoFileUpload-spec.js:8:27)
[firefox #1]         at addSpecsToSuite (C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:743:25)
[firefox #1]         at Env.describe (C:\Users\travi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:713:7)
[firefox #1] 
[firefox #1] 1 specs, 1 failures
[firefox #1] Finished in 0.015 seconds
[firefox #1] Shutting down selenium standalone server.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C:\Users\travi\Documents\protractor\Experiments\20151030\tests\OnlineDonation-Match-NoFileUpload-spec.js:8:27`

That is the important line. It indicates line 8, column 27 of the file referred to above.

Comment: That's kind of what I was afraid of. I think line 8 refers to my Require, which doesn't have a colon in it -- but leads to a file with two of them, but both valid.